# PHP file_get_contents() not working how to fix

Tags: php, json, session

What is the Difference and how can i fix this.

Why does this one work

```
$backupFile = file_get_contents("listbackup.json");
                    file_put_contents('list.json', $backupFile);
```

And when i use it like this it wont work.

This one is above HTML

```
 session_start();
 if(!isset($_SESSION['active']))
 {
    $backup=fopen("backup/".time().".json", "w");
    fwrite($backup, json_encode($list)); fclose($backup);
    if(isset($backup))
    {
        $_SESSION['active']=true;
    } 
 }
```

And this one goes after

```
 session_start();
                        if(isset($_SESSION['active']))
                        {
                            $path= "backup";

                            $latest_ctime = 0;
                            $latest_filename = '';

                            $d = dir($path);
                            while (false !== ($entry = $d->read())) 
                            {
                                $filepath = "{$path}/{$entry}";
                                if (is_file($filepath) && filectime($filepath) > $latest_ctime) 
                                {
                                    $latest_ctime = filectime($filepath);
                                    $latest_filename = $entry;
                                }
                            }
                                    $latest=file_get_contents($latest_filename); 
                                    file_put_contents('list.json', $latest);

                                    session_destroy(); 
                        }
```

When i try to get the content from the $latest_filename its gives me a false Bool and i cant get any further with it. What i need is to put the content in list.json thats all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
$latest_filename = $entry;
```

To:

```
$latest_filename = $path.'/'.$entry;
```

You're inside `$path` looking for your file, but when you try to reach it, you need to go inside `$path` again, otherwise you'll never find it.

Comment: Damn my bad, ahahahahah didnt see that one!! Thank you very much for your help